# How can I force youtube to use the max res thumbnail image

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to set up my youtube video to only use the max res thumbnail image for any device including mobile. It seems to choose the best image for a particular device. I want to override this ability and force the thumbnail to be max res all the time. How can I do this? Is there a setting in YouTube channel settings? Is there a query string I can use in my iframe? Am I asking for something that is possible?

Answer (score -1):

There is a way. You need to provide different link to the video, for example:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/hqdefault.jpg
```

or

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg
```

where `VIDEO_ID` is your `videoid`.

Look also here: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: Yes I know about this, but a plugin my boss purchased uses this iframe: https://www.youtube.com/embed/?controls=0&showinfo=0&fullscreen=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&wmode=opaque&vq=hd720&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.updog.com.au. Since its an iframe how can I update the thumbnail image. Its hard because I don't have direct access to youtube in the iframe. So if anyone knows the query string or setting in Youtube admin, that would be great